# $\tau$ is stopping time. Check if $\tau + 1$, $\tau - 1$, $\tau^2$ also are stopping time.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $\tau$ is stopping time. Is is true that

a) $\tau + 1$

b) $ \tau - 1 $

c) $ \tau^2 $

also are stopping time?

**My prove:**

a) Yes, because forall t we have $$\{ t: \quad \tau+1 \le t \} = \{ t: \quad \tau \le t-1 \} \subset \{ t: \quad \tau \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t  $$

c) very similar because we have 
$$\{ t: \quad \tau^2 \le t \} = \{ t: \quad \tau \in [\sqrt{t},\sqrt{t}] \} \subset \{ t: \quad \tau \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t  $$

Am I right in point a and c?

I think that $\tau - 1$ is not stopping time but how can I show it?

Comment: $A\subseteq B$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}_t$ does not imply that $A\in\mathcal{F}_t$. If that were the case, then $\mathcal{F}_t$ would contain every set.

Comment: Ok so could you tell me how show a) ?

Comment: Please provide your definition of being a stopping time. Something tells me you haven't got it entirely right judging from your attempt.

Comment: Stopping time is random variable $\tau$ such that forall $t \in T$ we have $\{ t: \tau \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ where $((\mathcal{F}_t : t \in T))$ is filtration.

Comment: No, it is $\{\omega: \tau(\omega)\leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$, as the other condition does not make sense. Usually, a stopping time is defined to be non-negative (at least when studying stochastic processes indexed by $[0,\infty)$). Is that the case here as well?

Comment: Yes, it was my wrong.

Comment: Then please revise your attempt. And is it now obvious that $\tau-1$ is not a stopping time?

Comment: Now I have problem with all points. In a) I have to show that forall $t \in T$ we have $\{ \omega : \tau(\omega) \le t-1 \} \in \mathcal{F}_t $. How can I get it?

Comment: If $T=[0,\infty)$, then distinguish between the two cases: $t<1$ and $t\geq 1$.

Comment: If $t<1$ then I have $t-1<0$ so $\{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \le 0 \} = \emptyset$. Of course it is in $\mathcal{F}_t$. But if $t\ge 1$ then I have $\{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \le c \} $ where $c>0$. It Is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ because iy is true for all $t$.

Comment: Well, you haven't used that $\tau$ is a stopping time yet. What does that tell you? And what is that mysterious $c$ you introduced?

Comment: $c=t-1$ and for $t \ge 1$ we have $c \ge 0$ so we consider set $\{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \le c \} $. But $\tau$ is stopping time so for all $t$ we have $\{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$, especially for $t=c$ we have $\{ \omega: \tau(\omega) \le t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$

Comment: "especially for t=c" - but you just said c=t-1. Anyhow, for $t\geq 1$ we have $\{\tau+1\leq t\}=\{\tau\leq t-1\}\in\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ and thus also $\{\tau+1\leq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$ (why?).

Comment: Because $\mathcal{F}_{t-1} \subset \mathcal{F}_t$ ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for you! But if I have $\tau -1$ I got $\{ \tau \le t+1 \} \in \mathcal{F}_{t+1}$. What should I do next?

Comment: Is $\tau-1$ necessarily non-negative?